# angularstrap bs-tooltip cause error: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-strap

When I am trying to use angularstrap tooltips it cause this error everytime load the project:

```
<span data-title="{{item.id}}" bs-tooltip delay="500"> </span>
```

It occur an error in console:

```
widgets.js:40761 TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
at TooltipFactory (http://localhost:9000/grunt-scripts/widget.js:66317:43)
```

Does anyone has experience with this, please help me ?

"EDITED": Here is the code of angular tooltip:

```
angular.module('mgcrea.ngStrap.tooltip', ['mgcrea.ngStrap.helpers.dimensions'])

  .provider('$tooltip', function() {

    var defaults = this.defaults = {
      animation: 'am-fade',
      customClass: '',
      prefixClass: 'tooltip',
      prefixEvent: 'tooltip',
      container: false,
      target: false,
      placement: 'top',
      template: 'tooltip/tooltip.tpl.html',
      contentTemplate: false,
      trigger: 'hover focus',
      keyboard: false,
      html: false,
      show: false,
      title: '',
      type: '',
      delay: 0,
      autoClose: false,
      bsEnabled: true
    };

    this.$get = ["$window", "$rootScope", "$compile", "$q", "$templateCache", "$http", "$animate", "$sce", "dimensions", "$$rAF", "$timeout", function($window, $rootScope, $compile, $q, $templateCache, $http, $animate, $sce, dimensions, $$rAF, $timeout) {

      var trim = String.prototype.trim;
      var isTouch = 'createTouch' in $window.document;
      var htmlReplaceRegExp = /ng-bind="/ig;
      var $body = angular.element($window.document);

      function TooltipFactory(element, config) {

        var $tooltip = {};

        // Common vars
        var nodeName = element[0].nodeName.toLowerCase();
        var options = $tooltip.$options = angular.extend({}, defaults, config);
        $tooltip.$promise = fetchTemplate(options.template);
        var scope = $tooltip.$scope = options.scope && options.scope.$new() || $rootScope.$new();
        if(options.delay && angular.isString(options.delay)) {
          var split = options.delay.split(',').map(parseFloat);
          options.delay = split.length > 1 ? {show: split[0], hide: split[1]} : split[0];
        }

        // store $id to identify the triggering element in events
        // give priority to options.id, otherwise, try to use
        // element id if defined
        $tooltip.$id = options.id || element.attr('id') || '';
```

The problem in this line:

```
var nodeName = element[0].nodeName.toLowerCase();
```

Comment: Could you please snippet of your JavaScript code? That will help us to give you an right answer. I suspect a correction there

Comment: I just added it in the edit question. please have a look.

Answer (score -1):

`Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined` means you try to run a method ([String.prototype.toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)) that belongs to a String object on an undefined variable.

```
function TooltipFactory(element, config) {

    var $tooltip = {};

    // Common vars
    var nodeName = element[0].nodeName.toLowerCase();
```

this is the problematic code, `element[0].nodeName` is undefined, which means `element[0]` doesn't have a property called `nodeName`. you can test it by printing the element object

```
console.debug("element[0] = %o", element[0]);
```

if `element[0]` is the `<span>` element you can just access the tooltip text using the `title` property

Comment: Thank you @svarog for the explaination, but what I want is use angurlarstrap tooltip not use the title of htlm. I also did a debug for it before while it throw the error log the variable element = 'tooltip' instead of span.